# How can I pass arguments from one thread to another thread continuously?

Tags: c, multithreading

How is it possible to send data from one running thread to another running thread in c language.
I want to generate data in main thread and send this data via a loop to another thread during each round trip of this loop.

```
// main 
int j = 0;    //initialize from 0
while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[1]);

    while (!flag[1])
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond[1], &mutex[1]);

    j++;
    if (j > 12)
        break;

    data[0] = orders[j];
    data[1] = j;
    thread_data_array[1].kilometer = data[0];
    thread_data_array[1].orders_num = data[1];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[1]);

    if (j == 1) {
        thread_data_array[1].th_num = 1;
        pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, threads, (void *) &thread_data_array[1]);
    }    
}

// another thread

data_th1 = (struct data_thread *) arg;

new_kilometer1 = data_th1->kilometer;
order_num1 = data_th1->orders_num;
num_th = data_th1->th_num;

//print results
```

But I will get only the first value of round trip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between thread using C issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741243/passing-data-between-thread-using-c-issue)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need to get a confirm signal from another thread then generate new data in main thread and pass this data to aforementioned thread.Your suggestion generate data first then pass all this data to second thread.

Comment: Proper approach is to create data in one thread and then pass it to another using signal info or queue.

Comment: can you give me more details please?

Comment: You want to be using a pipe in C.  Among other places, look here: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: You could use a `pipe` or you could use file global memory and mutex.  If the data is always the same size, a unnamed pipe would work very well.

Comment: the posted code is always placing the data into the same (second) location in the array of `struct data_thread` array  Suggest eliminate the array, so only have a single instance of the struct data_thread, then use the mutex to control access to a flag that indicates when the struct has a new/unconsumed data

Comment: the question is about a runtime problem.  Such problems, to get any complete answers, must include the actual input, the actual output, the expected output, and short code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code does not compile, is missing several data definitions, etc.

Comment: @S.far - I voted to leave this question open, but... I think you need to add the additional details to your question, like the detail about only one message is passed. Otherwise, the question as written begs for the dup.